# Sql query help for a beginner

Tags: sql

Hi i need a query help (and yes i have been trying to search but could not find something that helped me)

I have two tables:

**Customer**

- `CustomerID`
- `CountryID`

**Country**

- `CountryID`
- `Country`

How I would like to write a query to have result as following:

```
CountryID, Country, NumberOfOccurancesOfThisCountryInTheCustomerTable
```

Help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CountryID, Country,
  COUNT(Customer.CustomerID) AS NumberOfOccurancesOfThisCountryInTheCustomerTable
FROM Country LEFT JOIN
     Customer ON Country.CountryID = Customer.CountryID
GROUP BY Country.CountryID, Country.Country
```

**EDIT**: Using `LEFT JOIN` vs. `INNER JOIN` to include `Country` records that have zero `Customer` records (thanks Mark Bannister).

Comment: +1. Using a left join instead of an inner join would include Countries with 0 occurences in the Customer table.

Comment: @Yuck Thank you so much, this saved me alot of time and it works just the way i wanted it to!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it, assuming CustomerId is a primary key:

```
SELECT 
    Country.CountryId,
    Country.Country,
    COUNT(Customers.CustomerId)
FROM 
    Country INNER JOIN Customers ON Country.CountryId = Customers.CountryId
GROUP BY 
    CountryId, Country
```